# Magento on 8GB RAM VPS - MySQL performance

Tags: mysql, magento, vps

I've got VPS with 8GB RAM and 256GB SSD. Now, on that server, I have a Magento install that has ~100k products in it. That said, once a day I run an importer to go through products and import/update them, but it always fills up my memory and VPS goes unresponsive. I've 1GB PHP memory limit, and 5GB innodb_buffer_pool_size. Everything else is by default. My server is on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Can you give us more detail about what is filling the memory?

Comment: Well, importing products in Magento system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vast number of products, combined with poorly coded queries resulted in spending actually all the memory my VPS was assigned to, hence the MySQL restarting.